# Attaching a deattached object to context

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've got an application that in the UI can add categories that already exist in the DB to a product and then post it back to the backend.

But when I try to save it as below (Try 1 and 2), it does not save the attached categories to the database.

What am I missing?

```
 public bool SaveProduct(Product product) 
 {
    //Try 1
    foreach(var item in product.Categories) {
            db.Entry(item).State = item.Id == 0 ?
                EntityState.Added :
                EntityState.Modified;
        }
    //Try 2
    foreach(Category category in product.Categories) {
        db.Entry(category).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.Category.Attach(category);
    }
    return Save();
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: What does the `Save()` method do?

Comment: Its just `db.SaveChanges();` with loggin and error handling.

Answer (score 1):

The order is your problem.

First you set the entry of some category object in your context to Modified (which should retrieve the object with the same ConcurrencyTokens from the database and set the state to modified), 
and then attach your current object to the context (obviously in Unchanged state).

This will override the first call and, since no entries are modified or added, will not be persisted in the database.

Try reversing the order of Attach() and State=Modified.